# SCardResourceManager Listreader is causing Index was outside the bounds of the array error

Tags: c#

Objective: I need to get the UID(unique ID) of an HID smartcard using HID Omnikey Smart Card reader. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do it using PCSC (pcsc-sharp.dll). Thus, I searched for an alternative and I found cardwerk.

I'm a newbie in .NET and I'm testing a smartcard sample code that I found an evaluation version of a smartcard dll.

```
ArrayList m_vsReaderNames = new ArrayList();

private void InitializeSmartCardSystem()
        {
            if (m_aCardResourceManager == null)
            {
                m_aCardResourceManager = new SCardResourceManager();
                if (!m_aCardResourceManager.EstablishContext(SCardContextScope.User))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SCardResourceManager.EstablishContext failed!");
                    Application.Exit();
                }

                m_aCardResourceManager.ListReaders(m_vsReaderNames);
                if (m_vsReaderNames.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SCardResourceManager.ListReaders did not find any card readers!");
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
        }
```

This m_aCardResourceManager.ListReaders(m_vsReaderNames); part retrieves the following smart card information.

```
    [0] "H" object {string}
    [1] "I" object {string}
    [2] "D" object {string}
    [3] " " object {string}
    [4] "O" object {string}
    [5] "M" object {string}
    [6] "N" object {string}
    [7] "I" object {string}
    [8] "K" object {string}
    [9] "E" object {string}
    [10]"Y" object {string}
    [11]" " object {string}
    [12]"5" object {string}
```

Since indexID is not present from m_vsReaderNames variable on the above code, I encountered an error stating that Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Also, instead of having the arraylist values I would like to have a string value equal to "HID OMNIKEY 5" which will be displayed in a combo box shown on the attached file.!

for complete sample code please see http://smartcard-api.com/download.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking. It sounds like you want to join those values into a string? Here's a way you can do it.

```
var myString = string.Join("", m_vsReaderNames);
//myString now holds: "HID OMNIKEY 5"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's one of my concerns but I'm having a problem with the "Index was outside the bounds of the array." error on this part of code: 
m_aCardResourceManager.ListReaders(m_vsReaderNames); 
       
     public int ListReaders(IList aReadersList);
     public int ListReaders(string[] vsGroups, IList aReadersList);